# Ajax two clicks

Tags: jquery, ajax, click, double, hide

I have this jquery code for hiding Ad box after clicking on link in:

```
$('a.close').click(function () {
   var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
   var adid = $(parent).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "./setcookie.php",
       data: "adid=" + adid,
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (cook) {
           if (cook.set === 'success') {
               parent.fadeOut(1000);
           }
       },
       error: function () {
           $(".guestwarn").html("<font color='red'>There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.</font>").fadeIn(1000);
       }
   });
   return false;
```

});

So I would like by means of cookies close box.
My html(php) is:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE[ "msg1"])){?>
<div id="msg1" class="msgbox">
    <div class="guestwarn">
        <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
        Something goes here...
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

So my working setcookie.php is:

```
$adcookies = array();
$value = $_POST['adid'];
if ($value) {
    setcookie($value, $value, time() + 3600);
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$value])) {
        $adcookies['set'] = "success";
    } else {
        $adcookies['set'] = "error";
    }
    echo json_encode($adcookies);
}
```

Why adbox (.msgbox) hides after two clicks?
What is wrong with the codes?
Thank You

Comment: Please take the time to indent your code. Nobody wants to have to puzzle out this mess to understand your question.

Comment: @Wirey You've introduced formatting errors. You really shouldn't be editing other people's code this way.

Comment: tryed.Sorry for my English.

Comment: @meagar sorry.. did i mess it up big?  Was just indenting the code

Comment: after removing if (cook.set === 'success') statement will solve double click need problem, but... I need this statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet on the cookies. If you set a cookie it will be 'visible' to you after you refresh the page (in your case second AJAX request), so that's why you have to click twice. You can solve it using sessions instead of cookies.

Comment: but I can't hide ad box after session ends.